# iPython Code Completion / Intellisense on Dot Possible?

Tags: python, ipython

As someone trying to learn the ins and outs of Python (with emphasis on scientific computing - ie: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn), most of the gurus out there seem to recommend and use iPython notebooks.  My biggest sticking point as a beginner/intermediate coder is that I NEED code completion / intellisense -like functionality from an IDE to learn the function parameters.  I'm not hard-wired yet to just know what parameters are available at my current development.

In iPython, I noticed I can press `Tab` to show the drop-down of options (seen below as pd.) but I don't want to have to hit  each time.  That's not user-friendly for my needs.  Instead, I would like it to show only available classes and methods when I press dot.

Secondly, I notice that if I did say `pd.read_csv(<TAB>`, I get a lot more options than are the actual parameters in `read_csv`.

**Question**: Can iPython automatically show accurate code completion options instantly after pressing dot / period?  Also, is there a way to configure it to only show the available function parameters when within a function?

To make this question super-specific, I'm not asking about using any other IDE; I'm asking very specifically in regards to just iPython and wondering if there's a way to set some kind of configuration to achieve accurate "dot" display options instantly when pressing "dot" (no time delay).

[image]

Example below shows `Desktop` which is obviously not a parameter of `pd.read_csv()`.

[image]

Comment: Just mentioning a solution for full IntelliSense for JupyterLab I am working on: https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp (including completion on dot and signature suggestion). Not sure if this would qualify as an answer... - should I post one?

Comment: @krassowski looks like a potential answer to this question. auto invocation on '.' (dot) is the primary pain-point and purpose of this question. If you think your library is a solution, by all means feel free to contribute an answer in the context of this question.

Answer (score 62):

You can press `<Shift>-<Tab>` to get a tooltip showing the function's signature:

[image]

Alternatively, invoking `zip?` opens a documentation pane at the bottom of the window.

As far as having the tooltip open automatically, I'm unsure. I'd guess that it isn't possible via configuration.

Comment: Neither shortcut displays any hint for class members, functions parameters or anything. Is there anything else I've should install to enable?

Comment: @tutuca As far as I am aware, this should work without needing any packages other than jupyter. I'd suggest making sure that you have a recent version of jupyter installed, and perhaps looking to see if the shortcut is different on your operating system.

Comment: You are right, my libraries wasn't reloading, I just turned the notebook on and off and it started working. Thanks for replying :)

Comment: Is there a way to access this feature in the interactive IPython shell?

Comment: I have to write the complete function name to see its description. It doesn't show the list of functions to choose from.

Answer (score 44):

Almost 3 years later, I've finally come across a potential solution.

**Answer**: Install [nbextensions](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and enable the Hinterland extension.

> Enable code autocompletion menu for every keypress in a code cell,
>   instead of only calling it with tab.

Here's what you do:

1. `pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`
2. `jupyter contrib nbextension install --user`
3. Start `jupyter notebook` (browser launches)
4. One of the **tabs** should now show "**Nbextensions**"
5. There, you will find "**Hinterland**". Check the box to enable.

Hinterland has some adjustable options like:

- **hinterland.hint_delay**: delay in milliseconds between keypress & hint request.
- **hinterland.enable_at_start**: Whether to enable hinterland's continuous hinting when notebook is first opened, or if false, only when selected from the help-menu item.
- **hinterland.hint_inside_comments**: Whether to request hints while typing code comments. Defaults to false.
- **Other regex options**: hinterland.exclude_regexp, hinterland.include_regexp, hinterland.tooltip_regexp

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just solved my problem!

Comment: How to turn off auto completion in it?

Comment: If you are in a conda environment install it like this instead `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
`

Answer (score 8):

Now there's a better way to get accurate code completion operation. It can be triggered by any character you typed. Inspired by TabNine, I developed a code auto-completion extension for Jupyter Notebook [Jupyter TabNine](https://github.com/wenmin-wu/jupyter-tabnine).

It's available on [pypi index](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-tabnine/) now.  Simply issue following commands, then enjoy it:)

```
pip3 install jupyter-tabnine
jupyter nbextension install --py jupyter_tabnine
jupyter nbextension enable --py jupyter_tabnine
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_tabnine
```

---

[image: demo]

Comment: TabNine is the all language completer https://www.tabnine.com/. It works for .NET. And we can make this jupyter plugin work for .NET simply by changing one line code. You can create an issue here: https://github.com/wenmin-wu/jupyter-tabnine/issues

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me:

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
jupyter notebook
```

To see the Nbextensions tab if something has hidden it:

```
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

- under Nbextensions uncheck "disable confirguration for nbextensions without explicit compatibility ..." (disclaimer - all risks are yours for doing this)
- select **only**

  - "Hinterland" for the formatting ones. I had some other nbextensions selected and somehow it was not working.
  - "Nbextension edit menu item" & "Nbestenision dashboard tab" (in order to see this tab again next time)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Jupyter notebook and your Intellisense is not working then type below and give a press TAB after (.)

%config IPCompleter.greedy=True

it will work for you as well.

Comment: It's hard for me to tell if this answers their question or just suggests pressing tab after the `.` (which is explicitly what the user wishes to avoid in their question).

Comment: as of now we don't have anything that can avoid pressing Tab. May be in future...

Answer (score 4):

If you are using JupyterLab, the [jupyterlab-lsp extension](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp) (with pyls server installed) does invoke the completer automatically upon typing the dot (or any character if told so):

[image]

Pros:

- completion suggestions are available even before the code gets executed (static analysis)
- documentation panel can be displayed for the completion candidates
- type icons (with different themes available)
- other IDE features included (signature hints, diagnostics, rename, etc)

Cons:

- not yet as configurable as Hinterland (but it is getting there)
- some users prefer to only get completions for objects in already executed cells

Assuming Python 3.6+ and JupyterLab 3.0+ are already installed:

```
pip install jupyterlab-lsp    # client and server extension
pip install jedi-language-server     # fast language server, or
# pip install python-language-server[all]     # another language server
```

For more detailed and up-to-date installation instructions please [see this link](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp#installation).

Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of this extension.

Comment: For those like me stuck on python3.6, the highest supported versions of the libraries above are: ``python -m pip install jedi-language-server==0.21.0 jedi==0.17.2 ipython==7.16.1``

Answer (score 2):

For `Mac` in `JupyterLab` just press **`tab`**