# How to get code completion in a Jupyter notebook running in Docker

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, code-completion

I followed the instructions on the official [Tensorflow Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow) to be able to use a GPU-ready docker image with an exposed port for local Jupyter notebook development; including installation of the required `nvidia-docker`

I can import packages no problem, but code completion doesn't work when hitting tab. E.g:

```
import tensorflow as tf       # works fine
tf. <tab>                     # nothing happens
```

I can use the code if I type I manually. I can execute the following:

```
import numpy as np            # no complaints
np.arange(0, 10)              # returns expected result
```

Interestingly, if I type `tf.` and hit `shift-<double-tab>` I get the usually full docstring:

[image]

---

I used the following command to pull the docker image and run it:

```
docker run -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -it --runtime=nvidia --rm \
    -v $(realpath ~/Documents/jupyter_notebooks):/tf/notebooks \
    -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

On top of binding a local folder to the container, this maps my user ID to the running container, so I am not working from *root*'s home folder (my docker installation is made to belong to *root*. I can open the notebook directory in the browser and start a new Python3 notebook, as usual.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, opening Jupyter notebooks in Chrome (I use **vimium** extension, but it is switched off and I restarted the container after figuring it might be messing with keyboard commands sent to Chrome).

```
$  docker --version
Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a quick and [easy solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51599952/3126298) - just run one of the Jupyter magic commands:

```
%config IPCompleter.greedy=True
```

Also worked in a Jupyter notebook running within PyCharm. As soon as I ran that command, PyCharm began indexing the project, meaning code completion worked in scripts as well as in the notebook (which also hadn't been working!)

It should be possible to add the config parameter to a global Jupyter config file.

---

There is a second possible solution on the same thread, using a notebook extension, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Here is the [**relevant documentation for `%config`**](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-config)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. I also am using the tensorflow docker with gpu on Ubuntu 18.04 :/

Answer (score 4):

Wenmin Wu's tabnine plugin is definitely a better auto-completion service than the built-in.

I want to point out that IPython uses Jedi to do auto-completion and some other magics. However, the compatibility between the duo is problematic every now and then. Besides waiting for an IPython update, an easy fix is this magic:

```
%config IPCompleter.use_jedi=False
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plugin for jupyter notebook which provide code autocompletion based on deep learning model. It's C/S model, and can be run everywhere. You can try this: https://github.com/wenmin-wu/jupyter-tabnine
This tool is now available on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-tabnine/). Simply issue following **four** lines command and enjoy it:)

```
pip3 install jupyter-tabnine
jupyter nbextension install --py jupyter_tabnine
jupyter nbextension enable --py jupyter_tabnine
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_tabnine
```

[image: demo]