# Hinterland autocompleting words in jupyter lab even without hitting enter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am using Hinterland for suggestions while I am typing but sometimes it autocompletes the word without even letting me hit enter and it's kind of irritating.
For eg, when I type "import pa" it automatically converts to "import pandas". I only want suggestions of pandas and if I want to type it I will hit enter, same as in VS Code. Is there any way to disable this auto complete feature without turning of suggestions too?

Comment: This sounds like you might be using an old version of JupyterLab. What is your JupyterLab version? Also, there is no Hinterland for JupyterLab itself, but you might be using [`jupyterlab-lsp`](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp) - is it the extension that you are using?

Comment: @krassowski my jupyterlab version is 2.2.6 and I used the second answer of following link to install hinterland. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700112/ipython-code-completion-intellisense-on-dot-possible

Comment: In that case You installed hinterland for jupyter Notebook not for JupyterLab. I recommend updating to JupyterLab 3 and installing the LSP extension.

Comment: @krassowski Thanks for helping me. I have updated to JupyterLab 3 but I have trouble installing LSP extension. I have referred https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp and https://jupyterlab-lsp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation.html . Can you please help me installing it. I am using Windows and have anaconda installed and using jupyter lab from there only. Thanks in advance. You can also write as answer if you want.

Comment: What do you have a trouble with?

Comment: @krassowski When I am running "conda install -c conda-forge 'jupyterlab>=3.0.0,<4.0.0a0' jupyterlab-lsp" this command, I am getting the error "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with your conda installation. Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057291/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-in-anaconda-command-prompt or you could contact Anaconda support